# How to use custom substitutions with secretmanager in cloudbuild?

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager, cloudbuild.yaml, secret-manager

I'm having an issue with using custom substitutions in my cloudbuild.yaml.

```
substitutions:
  _CUSTOM_SUBSTITUTION: this-is-a-path
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$_CUSTOM_SUBSTITUTION/secrets/client_id/versions/1
    env: CLIENT_ID
  - versionName: projects/$_CUSTOM_SUBSTITUTION/secrets/client_secret/versions/1
    env: CLIENT_SECRET
```

From what I can tell from trial and error, using something like `$PROJECT_ID` in the place of `$_CUSTOM_SUBSTITUTION` will run the build, but if I use a custom substitution like above, the trigger does not run a build at all when a commit is pushed.

I've also tested with various other base substitutions, like `$BRANCH_NAME` to the same effect. I'm getting the feeling that it's just not possible to do this in cloudbuild at the moment?

Comment: Can you share your trigger configuration?

Comment: I'm using "Push to a Branch" as the invoking event trigger. It's set to use a Cloud Build configuration file (this cloudbuild.yaml), which is being read from my repo. Other than that, I'm not using an substitution variables from the GCP UI, only via the substitution line in the cloudbuild.yaml.

I've had successful builds prior to this, it was only the introduction of this availableSecrets section that they started not being triggered

Comment: Can you share your [logs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs#viewing_build_logs) related to Cloud Build? I have not tested it yet, but something worth trying is to use the syntax `${_CUSTOM_SUBSTITUTION}` *with the curly braces,* as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions) shows that this allows custom substitutions to work when **not** surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a combination of need curly braces `${_CUSTOM_SUBSTITUTION}` and some syntax fixing in the cloudbuild.yaml. I didn't have enough experience with cloudbuild to find that.

The offending part was something this:

`AUTH_TOKEN=$$(cat /workspace/token.txt)`. Originally I had just 1 $ there, which was also working code pulled from another project.

For anyone running into this in the future, using `gloud builds submit` can let you run it directly for troubleshooting.